# validate input field which allows me to enter character

Tags: validation, input

I want to validate the input field which allows me to enter a character, number, and special chars. But I want to restrict to entering only special chars. Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

pattern = '^(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]';

this pattern solved my problem.